# Favicon without HTML code

Tags: html, favicon

I noticed that [Future Friendly](http://futurefriend.ly/)'s source code doesn't contain any code for their favicon. Yet, there is a blue star as their favicon in my browser's tab. Is this witchcraft?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can just put a `favicon.ico` file in the root level of the website. in your sample http://futurefriend.ly/favicon.ico

Comment: I don't think there's any need to repeat answers.

Comment: There is no repeat here; this answer makes the important point that the name of the file is favicon.ico to have it automatically read. Your answer does not say that, leaving the OP to guess.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need code to reveal a favicon. Simply add the image to your site root folder and all newer browser (IE 7 +?) find it and show it automatically.

Comment: You can, however force the favicon to appear in older browsers with code. I goess Future Friendly is only looking towards the future.