# How to set default icon for each page for my website

Tags: html, favicon

I have seen some servers have default page icon for each pages without having to add using html.
example:

> http://facebook.com
>
> http://google.com

and even
the site in which we are i.e

> http://stackoverflow.com

on this sites the html code `<link href="url" rel="icon" type="type"/>` is not used yet they have icon set for each page can you please tell me how it is done.

Comment: This probably applies. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8500220/2191572

Comment: <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">
  3rd line in the sourcecode

Comment: Facebook: `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/yl/r/H3nktOa7ZMg.ico" />`

Comment: you can read about favicons here: http://www.maxi-pedia.com/Favicon+how+to+create

Comment: If you inspect the page on Google you will find `<meta content="/images/google_favicon_128.png" itemprop="image">` in the head

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not related to .htaccess (or PHP). Browsers automatically request a `/favicon.ico` file when loading a page. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) and Google can tell you more.

Comment: And additionally, the html addition for favicons helps prevent the server from making redundant fallback requests when autodetecting

Answer (score 1):

Put the file favicon.ico in the root of your domain.  That should solve your problem.